# Postgres 'date_trunc' function with 'at time zone'

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to use the date_trunc function with a specific time zone where the argument is selected from a column.

It works without 'at time zone':

```
SELECT (date_trunc('day', transactions.created_at))::DATE AS period_start FROM transactions LIMIT 1
```

It also works when the argument passed in is a string:

```
SELECT (date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP '2015-09-04 16:00:00' at time zone '+08:00'))::DATE AS period_start FROM transactions LIMIT 1
```

But when I tried to combine the two like so:

```
SELECT (date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP transactions.created_at at time zone '+08:00'))::DATE AS period_start FROM transactions LIMIT 1
```

It gave me a 'syntax error at or near "transactions"'.

I tried using to_char to cast it to string but had no luck either. How can I make this work?

Comment: If you want to cast your `created_at` field, you have to write like this:  `cast (transactions.created_at as timestamp)`

Comment: @Houari I feel so silly, that was so simple. Thanks so much for your help! You wanna write that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cast your `created_at field`, you have to write like this as following:

```
 CAST (transactions.created_at as timestamp)
```

So your final query should be something like:

```
SELECT (date_trunc('day', CAST (transactions.created_at as timestamp) at time zone '+08:00'))::DATE AS period_start 
FROM transactions LIMIT 1
```